# gradle custom war task webAppDirName

Tags: war, gradle

I have a few gradle war tasks in my build file, and I would like to change the `webAppDirName` per war task. I tried this:

```
task myWarTask(type: War) {
    ext.webAppDirName = 'src/anotherfolder/webapp' // also tried just webAppDirName
    version ""
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/libs")
    baseName = 'myWarName'
    classpath = configurations.myWarConfiguration
}
```

But this is still pulling in the contents of `src/main/webapp` instead of `src/anotherfolder/webapp`

Can I configure the `webAppDirName` on a per war file basis like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is just one `webAppDirName` property per project, and the War plugin automatically adds a corresponding `from` to each `War` task. So the main problem is how to undo that `from`. I think the following should work:

```
apply plugin: "war"

webAppDirName = "non/existing/dir"

task myWarTask(type: War) {
    from "src/anotherfolder/webapp"
    ...
}
```

An alternative is to only use the `War` task type, but not the War plugin. You'll have to configure a few more task properties then, and will lose a few features, mostly related to *provided* configurations and publishing of the War. Of course you can make up for this with explicit configuration (if necessary). If you are interested in the details, have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/WarPlugin.java) for the War plugin.

PS: `webAppDirName` is not an extra property (`ext.`), but a convention property added by the `War` plugin. Extra properties are only meant for ad-hoc use in build scripts. You'd use `ext.` when writing an extra property, but omit it when reading the property.

Comment: Now that I think of it, it might be cleaner just not to have a `src/main/webapp` directory.

Comment: I ended up just excluding the `src/main/webapp` since it included files for one of the other war tasks. It might be cleaner to break this war into a separate project.

Comment: they couldn't just have webAppDirName be a property of a War task instance?  Perhaps we should submit a bug/feature request to make that change?

Answer (score 1):

```
task myWarTask(type: War) {
    from 'src/anotherfolder/webapp'
    version ""
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/libs")
    baseName = 'myWarName'
    classpath = configurations.myWarConfiguration
}
```

Comment: This does include the files from src/anotherfolder/webapp but it still includes files from src/main/webapp