# Gradle multiproject: How refer correctly any content from WEB-INF for testing

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am working with a Spring/Gradle multi module project.

- For the modules, is possible test a specific module and it pass
- I am able to create a `.war` file and works in `Apache Tomcat`

The problem is about testing and is for the module working in a web environment. I have the following:

```
project(':web-27-controller') {
    description 'Web - Controller & Rest'

    dependencies {

       compile project(':web-27-service-api')
       compile project(':web-27-support')

       testCompile project(':web-27-config')
       testRuntime project(':web-27-config').sourceSets.test.output
       testRuntime project(':web-27-repository-jdbc')
       testRuntime project(':web-27-service-impl')
       testCompile project(':web-27-web')
       testRuntime project(':web-27-web').sourceSets.main.output

    }

}
```

In that module I have all about `@Controller`s

When I execute the test for that specific module, I get:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/tiles/definition/tiles-definitions.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getURL(ServletContextResource.java:156)
```

Well I can see in the *other* `web-27-web` module the `/WEB-INF/tiles/definition/tiles-definitions.xml` file. It of course within the `webapp` directory and remember, when I create the `.war` file, it works fine in `Apache Tomcat`

I know that Gradle respects or uses:

- src/main/java
- src/main/resources
- src/test/java
- src/test/resources

But seems that is not referring to the `WEB-INF` location

I have the following about `web-27-web` (consider it unstable because I have trying to get this working)

```
project(':web-27-web') {
    description 'Web (JSP, JS, CSS)'

    apply plugin: 'war'
    project.webAppDirName = 'WebContent'

    dependencies {

        compile fileTree(dir: "WebContent/WEB-INF/tiles/definition", include: '*.xml')
        testCompile fileTree(dir: "WebContent/WEB-INF/tiles/definition", include: '*.xml')
        testRuntime fileTree(dir: "WebContent/WEB-INF/tiles/definition", include: '*.xml')

        exportedProjects.each{
            if("$it"!=":web-27-web")
                compile project("$it")
        }

        //Apache Tiles
        ['tiles-jsp',
         'tiles-servlet'
        ].each {
            runtime "org.apache.tiles:$it:$tilesVersion"
            testCompile "org.apache.tiles:$it:$tilesVersion" 
            testRuntime "org.apache.tiles:$it:$tilesVersion"            
         }

        //JSTL
        compile "javax.servlet:jstl:$jstlVersion"
        testRuntime "javax.servlet:jstl:$jstlVersion"

        //Servlet API
        providedCompile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:$javaxServletApiVersion"
        testRuntime "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:$javaxServletApiVersion"

    }

    war {
        version=''
        baseName = warBaseName
    }

}
```

What is missing or wrong?

**Alpha**:

When I use either (1) or (2)

```
project(':web-27-web') {
    description 'Web (JSP, JS, CSS)'

    apply plugin: 'war'
    webAppDirName = 'WebContent'//1
    webAppDirName = 'weapp'//2

    dependencies {

        ...

        //JSTL
        compile "javax.servlet:jstl:$jstlVersion"

        //Servlet API
        providedCompile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:$javaxServletApiVersion"

    }
...
```

Just how playing, when I export the project to a `.war` file and it is deployed in Tomcat, I did realise that the `resources` (where should be located all .js, css files) does not exist and the unique content in `WEB-INF` is the `lib` directory.

I must use `webAppDirName = 'src/main/webapp'` to have a successful exportation.

```
project(':web-27-web') {
    description 'Web (JSP, JS, CSS)'

    apply plugin: 'war'
    webAppDirName = 'src/main/webapp'

    dependencies {

        compile fileTree(dir: "/WEB-INF/tiles/definition", include: '*.xml')
        runtime fileTree(dir: "/WEB-INF/tiles/definition", include: '*.xml')
        testCompile fileTree(dir: "/WEB-INF/tiles/definition", include: '*.xml')
        testRuntime fileTree(dir: "/WEB-INF/tiles/definition", include: '*.xml')

        exportedProjects.each{
            if("$it"!=":web-27-web")
                compile project("$it")
        }

        //JSTL
        compile "javax.servlet:jstl:$jstlVersion"

        //Servlet API
        providedCompile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:$javaxServletApiVersion"

    }
```

But Testing does not detect or recognize about the location and content from `WEB-INF` yet.

Comment: Does it work just with `webAppDirName = 'WebContent'`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392919/gradle-custom-war-task-webappdirname. OTOH why don't follow with defaults when we use `webapp` on the same level as `resources` and `java`?..

Comment: I will check the other post and your suggestion. Normally in any tutorial that uses Tiles, always that files are located within `WEB-INF` (until here, 99.99% are based in one module). Now consider `Spring MVC Test with HtmlUnit` where the `JSP` files are located within `WEB-INF` too. The unique exception are the `JS` and `CSS` files.

Comment: You didn't understand me. Everything is good unless I'd rename  `WebContent` to `webapp`, like it is by default in `war` Gradle plugin

Comment: See `Alpha` content.

Comment: Eh... Sorry, I'm not well with WEB facet. Try to find some info from the https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/sample_list.html

Comment: No worries, I have moved the tile file to `src/main/resources`, now works that module, but when the time to play with `Spring MVC Test with HtmlUnit` arrives I will ask for support to Rob, I think he is involved in that project.